# How do I get an xpath using Firepath plugin

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm not able to get an `xpath` using `FirePath`. I want to locate  username field of a login form using `xpath` in Firepath. But when I try to find the same element,
I'm getting `xpath` like :

```
html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/input
```

How can I use it in Selenium script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it like:-

```
 WebElement ele1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/input"));
 ele1.sendKeys("username");
```

Here username in double quotes would be replaced by actual value you want to enter in username field.

Answer (score 0):

This is also xpath which is called `absolute xpath` If you are looking for `relative xpath` then uncheck the option as shown in below image

[image]

And you can use this xpath like :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("username");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via the by.xpath

```
webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/input")).click();
```

You can also search for a relative xpath witch is more robust have a look at [this](http://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html) for more information of xpath.

Also have a look at [locators in selenium](https://www.protechtraining.com/bookshelf/selenium_tutorial/locators?ncr=1) for more information about the diffrent locators